# linux alternative to casablanca

Tags: c++, rest, asynchronous, webserver

Is there a Linux alternative to Microsoft's [Casablanca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx) library.
We will use the library for developing a web server.
Library should be written in C++, support REST services and based on asynchronous operations.
We have a D alternative: [vibe.d](http://vibed.org/) but a C++ library would be better as we are more experienced in C++.

Comment: You should try asking at their forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/casablanca/threads

Answer (score 4):

I think Casablanca is targeting on both Linux and windows, though current devlab release are windows only. Linux should be part of it very soon, and please feel free to ask any questions on Casablanca forum.